# Django: app_label problem when declaring base models outside models.py

Tags: django, inheritance, django-syncdb

I have an abstract Container class which allows derived models to hold some content blocks such as images, text, etc., which are also separate models. For db tidiness, I want tables for those models to be labeled as content_block_image, content_block_text, etc.

But when I specify `app_label = 'content_block'` in Meta class of Content model, I am getting an error during syncdb:

> content.event: 'content' has an m2m relation with model Content, which has either not been installed or is abstract.

I am declaring the following base classes as follows:

```
# base.py
class Content(models.Model):
    tags = models.TextField(_('tags'), blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, 
                                     related_name='%(class)s_content_set')

    container_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    container_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    container = generic.GenericForeignKey('container_type', 'container_id')

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'content_block'

class Container(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, 
                                     related_name='%(class)s_container_set')
    content = generic.GenericRelation('Content', 
                                      content_type_field='container_type', 
                                      object_id_field='container_id')
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Then, in my models I am declaring models I call container such as:

```
# models.py
class Event(Container):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    end = models.DateTimeField()
```

If I remove the `app_label` syncdb runs without a problem. It seems that app_label is not just a label.

Any ideas on how to get this going with the app_label for the Content base class set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the doc](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#app-label)

> If a model exists outside of the standard models.py (for instance, if the app’s models are in submodules of myapp.models), the model must define which app it is part of:
>
> ```
> app_label = 'myapp'
> ```

`content_block` application exists ? if not, i'm not shure it will work.

It seems that what you want to do is forcing the table names. It's possible will this property

> The name of the database table to use for the model:
>
> db_table = 'music_album'

Comment: you are right, `db_table` is the parameter. but then, as this is a base model that others are inherited, i want all the inherited models to be named in that format. thus it should accept a class name parameter similar to the related_name field attribute, i.e. `db_table = content_block_%(class)s`, but it doesn't.

Comment: how can the model name of the inheriting model can be accessed from within the Meta class? can the db_table attribute be parametrized by that such as `db_table = content_block_%s % inheriting_model_name`?